# Antd, How can I disable row of editable cell of Table

Tags: reactjs, antd

I use Editable Cell of Table

I want to disable row when age value is '33' include select(=checkbox)

There is sandbox test code

help me

[test code](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-golick-f5poev?file=/src/App.js:0-4222)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Table property called rowSelection.

You can pass to a function the record (the row you are editing or want to disable) and check inside the age.value if it's equal with 33.

For more check this link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/76pyq5?file=/demo.js:1601-1614